# Add/Initialize scala Inmutable Map to mutable Map

Tags: scala, dictionary, initialization

The question is very simple, is there a way in scala to initialize a Mutable map with a inmutable map?

**I want something like this:**

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{ Map => MutableMap }
...
val dumbMap = Map("abc" -> 123)
val theMap = new MutableMap(dumbMap)
```

of course I could iterate or use the map function to initialize my mutable map and add all the elements in `dumbMap`, but... it think it would be ridiculous if scala lacks of such a basic method

**SOLUTION EDIT:**
as mentioned in the previous question, it is not exactly a constructor, but a Method in its companion

```
val theMap = MutableMap[String, Integer](dumbMap.toSeq: _*)
```

*Pay attention to the types of your map*

Comment: The `scala.collection.mutable.Map` companion object has an `apply((A, B)*)` method ( http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map$@apply[A,B](elems:(A,B)*):CC[A,B] ), so you can do the following: `val theMap = MutableMap(dumbMap)` (note: no `new` there).

Comment: I have tried without the new word also and ... it is not working for me, I'll double check my sintax

Comment: @GáborBakos (A, B)* != Map[A,B]... this won't work.